# Android: trying to make a button play an audio, but I have an error when using the create(context, int)

Tags: android, media-player

I'm making an application and what a button to play a noise when its pushed, i have the audio .mp3 file stored in my res/raw directory, but i have an error under my create. it says "The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int)".

My code looks like this

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

private MediaPlayer mp;




        but_play = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.play_but);



    but_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            if (rot < 45 && rot > -45) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "the Cow says moo!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cow);
                mp.start();
```

else if statements continue from here for other animals

please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In this line you are passing in `this` which at that point is a reference to the `View.onClickListener`, what it is expecting is a `Context`.

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cow);
```

Try changing it to this:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.cow);
```